# Offload data independent

Tags: openmp, xeon-phi, offloading

I have problem with my project. I try to send data to be independent on xeon phi from CPU.

```
int test=5;

#pragma offload target(mic0) in(test)
{
    test=3;
}
printf("test equals %i", test);
```

And result is 3. I don't understand this, the test shouldn't still equals 5?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with MPI. Editing accordingly.

Comment: Maybe it runs in CPU fallback mode?